# How to work with an advisor that changes their mind regarding project scope?

Tags: advisor

I've been working with an advisor that has changed her mind regarding project scope for the past two projects I've been working with her. (So far I've only started two projects with her)

For the first project, we were thinking of building a system with two components, A and B. I worked weekdays and weekends on the project for one month, but she decided to drop component A and only keep component B. She mentioned that she would like some collaborators to join the project, and they would only be interested in component B. I was disappointed, but yielded when the advisor insisted.

The second project started six months after the first project started (the first project is still ongoing). For the second project, we decided we wanted to test the effectiveness of a certain class of interventions (call this class C). Bearing in mind that my advisor might change their mind, I worked less quickly on this project, avoiding overtime as much as possible so as to be flexible to a possible change of mind. (My advisor did say that I was working too slowly, but those were minor complaints) I roughly spent one day a week on the project for two months. At the two month mark, she said she wanted to study a much broader class of interventions (call this class D), which meant that most of the previous work was wasted as class C was only a small subset of class D (maybe only 10% of the size). She didn't give any reason initially, but when pressed, she mentioned that it would be good to combine this project with an upcoming project which touched on class D.

How can I deal with an advisor that changes their mind regarding project scope? On the one hand, I can't work too quickly as I will be too emotionally frustrated if things change. On the other hand, if I work too slowly, she may not be happy, and I may not have enough publications.

Comment: Consider changing advisor, ie find an advisor that knows what they want...

Comment: At what educational level is this, please? Is this doctoral or MS level research? Or is it projects for a class?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how work towards Class C is wasted work when Class D contains Class C. It's hard to determine from your question if these changes in scope are part of the normal changes in research scope as projects progress, or whether your advisor is jumping from place to place. Have you actually had a conversation with your advisor about your concerns?